# Projection onto column space perturbed by Gaussian noise

Tags: linear-algebra, probability-theory, statistics, random-matrices, concentration-of-measure

Suppose we have a matrix $X\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ (with $n \le m$) with iid standard Gaussian entries, and suppose we have noise matrix $W\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ with iid Gaussian entries, but with some small variance $\sigma_W < 1$. We know that the columns of $X$ and $X+W$ are linearly independent almost surely, so they form a basis. I am interested in knowing how the noise $W$ changes the projection matrix $X(X^TX)^{-1}X^T$ of $X$. For instance, denoting $X_W = X+W$ and $x_j$ as the jth column of $X$, can we say anything about $X_W(X_W^TX_W)^{-1}X_W^Tx_j$? I am especially interested in references that discuss this kind of problem. I know standard matrix perturbation theory results could be applied on this (suggestion on this is also welcomed!), but I am in particular interested in the high-dimensional regime, that is, when $n$ and/or $m$ are large, are there concentration results available?